# How to vary the ID query for findIndex()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I know that to find the index of a certain attribute in a key-value array, you can do this:

```
var index = peoples.findIndex(function(person) {
  return person.attr1 == "john"
}
```

However, what if I wanted to change "john" to a variable? For example, `targetID`?

My end goal is to get something like this:

```
function returnIndex (targetID) {
    var index = array.findIndex(function(x) {
        return x.id == targetID;
    });
}
```

To be honest I'm not sure if this will work. And if it does, I don't know how to *call* the function. How would I call this if it can work?

I'm really not familiar with this kind of js format since I'm only a few weeks into learning, sorry if these are very basic questions.

Comment: That should work, except that you're not returning `index` from the function `returnIndex`.

Comment: please share the `peoples` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the variable directly would work:

```
var targetID = "john";
var index = peoples.findIndex(function(person) {
  return person.attr1 == targetID;
}
```

To make that function of yours work, you'd have to also pass it the array, and make it return the index:

```
function returnIndex (array, targetID) { // added array,
    return array.findIndex(function(x) { // replaced `var index =` with `return`
        return x.id == targetID;
    });
}
// And use it like:
var index = returnIndex(peoples, "john");
```

Comment: Thank you! Instead of the first return I just added a `return index` to the end.

Comment: Yes, another possible solution. The local variable would be unnecessary, but it is a sensible approach if the programmer finds it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Your example does work with a little addition of `return index;` statement. See:

```js
var people = [
  { id: 0, name: "Matt" },
  { id: 1, name: "Tom" },
  { id: 2, name: "John" },
  { id: 3, name: "David" }
];


function returnIndex (targetID) {
    var index = people.findIndex(function(x) {
        return x.id == targetID;
    });
    return index;
}

console.log("In: 0, Out:", returnIndex(0));
console.log("In: 1, Out:", returnIndex(1));
console.log("In: 2, Out:", returnIndex(2));
console.log("In: 3, Out:", returnIndex(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it like pass `array` and `targetID` to the function and also you need to return the `index` from the function.

```
function returnIndex (array, targetID) {
    // here using es6 arrow function.       
    return array.findIndex(x => x.id === targetID)
}

// Calling the function
// array the array of objects, targetID the id of the target object
const index = returnIndex(array, targetID);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the variable `array` is not in the scope of the `returnIndex` function, you'll need to pass it as a parameter. Here is an example:

```
function returnIndex(array, targetID) {
    return array.findIndex(function(x) {
        return x.id == targetID;
    });
}

// And you call the function like this:

var index = returnIndex(peoples, targetId);
```